# Understand tensorflow slice operation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am confused about the follow code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

'''
Randomly crop a tensor, then return the crop position
'''
def random_crop(value, size, seed=None, name=None):
    with ops.name_scope(name, "random_crop", [value, size]) as name:
        value = ops.convert_to_tensor(value, name="value")
        size = ops.convert_to_tensor(size, dtype=dtypes.int32, name="size")
        shape = array_ops.shape(value)
        check = control_flow_ops.Assert(
                math_ops.reduce_all(shape >= size),
                ["Need value.shape >= size, got ", shape, size],
                summarize=1000)
        shape = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies([check], shape)
        limit = shape - size + 1
        begin = tf.random_uniform(
                array_ops.shape(shape),
                dtype=size.dtype,
                maxval=size.dtype.max,
                seed=seed) % limit
        return tf.slice(value, begin=begin, size=size, name=name), begin

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
size = [10]
a = tf.constant(np.arange(0, 100, 1))

print (a.eval())

a_crop, begin = random_crop(a, size = size, seed = 0)
print ("offset: {}".format(begin.eval()))
print ("a_crop: {}".format(a_crop.eval()))

a_slice = tf.slice(a, begin=begin, size=size)
print ("a_slice: {}".format(a_slice.eval()))

assert (tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(a_crop, a_slice)).eval() == True)
sess.close()
```

outputs:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71
 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95
 96 97 98 99]
offset: [46]
a_crop: [89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98]
a_slice: [27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36]
```

There are two `tf.slice` options:

(1). called in function random_crop, such as `tf.slice(value, begin=begin, size=size, name=name)`

(2). called as `a_slice = tf.slice(a, begin=begin, size=size)`

The parameters (`values`, `begin` and `size`) of those two `slice` operations are the same.

However, why the printed values `a_crop` and `a_slice` are different and `tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(a_crop, a_slice)).eval()` is True?

Thanks

EDIT1
Thanks @xdurch0, I understand the first question now.
Tensorflow `random_uniform` seems like a random generator.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
size = [10]
np_begin = np.random.randint(0, 50, size=1)
tf_begin = tf.random_uniform(shape = [1], minval=0, maxval=50, dtype=tf.int32, seed = 0)
a = tf.constant(np.arange(0, 100, 1))

a_slice = tf.slice(a, np_begin, size = size)
print ("a_slice: {}".format(a_slice.eval()))
a_slice = tf.slice(a, np_begin, size = size)
print ("a_slice: {}".format(a_slice.eval()))

a_slice = tf.slice(a, tf_begin, size = size)
print ("a_slice: {}".format(a_slice.eval()))
a_slice = tf.slice(a, tf_begin, size = size)
print ("a_slice: {}".format(a_slice.eval()))

sess.close()
```

output

```
a_slice: [42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51]
a_slice: [42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51]
a_slice: [41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50]
a_slice: [29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38]
```

Comment: `tf.random_uniform` returns different values each time it is evaluated, so comparing things based on different evaluations of these random values is not sensible.

Comment: @xdurch0, your are right. Interesting, Tensorflow document mentioned that tf.random_uniform returns `A tensor of the specified shape filled with random uniform values.` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_uniform). But, it sounds like a `random generator` for me now, not `values.`. But why `tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(a_crop, a_slice)).eval() is True? Thanks,

Comment: To make things clearer, random operations produce a different value on each call to `run` or `eval`. So evaluating the `tf.equal(...)` operation works because only one random value is generated and both slices are computed from it. If you use the [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) object and call `run((a_crop, a_slice, tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(a_crop, a_slice)))` you receive two equal arrays and `True`.

Comment: @jdehesa Sorry, i am not sure if i understand `So evaluating the tf.equal(...) operation works because only one random value is generated and both slices are computed from it.` Then why the printed out values are different between `a_crop` and `a_slice` if `only one random value is generated and both slices are computed from it`? Thanks

Comment: @user200340 One random value is generated each time a TensorFlow computation is issued (a call to `tf.Session.run`, or `.eval()`). Whenever you call `.eval()`, that is one new computation, and a new random value is produced. Maybe you can see it more clearly like this, if you do `tf.stack([a_crop, a_slice]).eval()` you will get a tensor with to equal rows. If you call `tf.Session.run` with multiple tensors, all the computations in that call will use the same random values. Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: Now, I understand it. Thank you very much, If you post your answer, I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusing thing here is that `tf.random_uniform` (like every random operation in TensorFlow) produces a new, different value on each evaluation call (each call to `.eval()` or, in general, each call to `tf.Session.run`). So if you evaluate `a_crop` you get one thing, if you then evaluate `a_slice` you get a different thing, but if you evaluate `tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(a_crop, a_slice))` you get `True`, because all is being computed in a single evaluation step, so only one random value is produced and it determines the value of both `a_crop` and `a_slice`. Another example is this, if you run `tf.stack([a_crop, a_slice]).eval()` you will get a tensor with to equal rows; again, only one random value was produced. More generally, if you call `tf.Session.run` with multiple tensors to evaluate, all the computations in that call will use the same random values.

As a side note, if you actually need a random value in a computation that you want to maintain for a later computation, the easiest thing would be to just retrieve if with `tf.Session.run`, along with any other needed computation, to feed it back later through `feed_dict`; or you could have a `tf.Variable` and store the random value there. A more advanced possibility would be to use [`partial_run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#partial_run), an experimental API that allows you to evaluate part of the computation graph and continue evaluating it later, while maintaining the same state (i.e. the same random values, among other things).